# How to create an overlapping, repeating line pattern where each layer above masks(?) the one below in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to make a series of simple line-based patterns in Illustrator. Most of the patterns will repeat in a way that causes them to overlap each other but I don't want the ones in the background to be visible behind the foreground.

Is there a way to maybe fill in the space between the lines to block stuff behind? Or a way to mask (for lack of a better word - I'm not sure the proper terminology) the stuff behind?

[image: Overlapping wave pattern]

Comment: Put a half circle filled white behind the four lines before repeat it.

Comment: That seems embarrassingly obvious. [rough](https://i.imgur.com/ZOtA3iT.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create two arches, stroke = black, fill = white

[image: Arcs]

- **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Make**
- **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Blend Options** > **Specified Steps** = 2

[image: Blend]

- Select the *Blend Object* > **Menu Object** > **Pattern** > **Make**
- Type = **Brick by Row**
- Reduce the vertical spacing
- Overlap = **Bottom in Front**

[image: pattern]

- Click **Done**

The Pattern has a white background. To use it over a color shape, from the **Transparency Panel**, change the blend mode to the shape with the pattern to **Multiply**.

[image: blend mode]